# Rails combine group by and min

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assume we have a table called `Activities`

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| player_id | device_id | event_date | games_played |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2         | 2016-03-01 | 5            |
| 1         | 2         | 2016-05-02 | 6            |
| 2         | 3         | 2017-06-25 | 1            |
| 3         | 1         | 2016-03-02 | 0            |
| 3         | 4         | 2018-07-03 | 5            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

I want to find out the `player_id` and it's **first** `event_date` as first_date.

SQL:

```
SELECT Activities.player_id, min(Activities.event_date) as first_date 
FROM `activities` 
GROUP BY `activities`.`player_id`
```

Result table:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| player_id | first_login |
+-----------+-------------+
| 1         | 2016-03-01  |
| 2         | 2017-06-25  |
| 3         | 2016-03-02  |
+-----------+-------------+
```

How to do it in Rails?

I've tried this one but retrieve an `Activity` collection which only contains `player_id`.

```
Activity.select('Activities.player_id, min(Activities.event_date) as first_date')
        .group(:player_id)
```

Like this

```
[#<Activity:0x00007f94923bb888 player_id: 1>, #<Activity:0x00007f94923bb608 player_id: 2>, #<Activity:0x00007f94923b9ba0 player_id: 3>]
```

Comment: When you assign a custom name in a select statement, rails will automatically create it as method name on the objects. e.g. `activities = [#<Activity:0x00007f94923bb888 player_id: 1>]; activities.first.first_date`

Comment: Try doing `to_json` and you will be able to see the `first_date` as well.

Comment: How on earth did you get that SQL output? It makes no sense at all that you selected `SELECT Activities.player_id, min(Activities.event_date) as first_date` and got `player_id` and `device_id` in the results. That just does not happen.

Comment: @max, I apologize, I put the totally wrong column name. Table has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your above query result

```
result = [#<Activity:0x00007f94923bb888 player_id: 1>, #<Activity:0x00007f94923bb608 player_id: 2>, #<Activity:0x00007f94923b9ba0 player_id: 3>]
```

loads first_date column, as first_date is not the attribute of Activity Object and rails do not display the virtual columns in this way.
You can access it using this syntax

`result.last.first_date`

If you need to see date value in result objects then modify your query like this

```
Activity.select('Activities.player_id, min(Activities.event_date) as event_date').group(:player_id)
```

then you will be able to get your desired result

```
<Activity:0x00007f94923bb608 player_id: 2, event_date: 'date value' >, #<Activity:0x00007f94923b9ba0 player_id: 3, event_date: 'date value' >]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the result you got only player_id because when you do `Activity.select('..')`, rails returns ActiveRecord model object.

You probably want to run a custom query and convert the output to an array like this:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT Activities.player_id, min(Activities.event_date) as first_date FROM activities GROUP BY activities.player_id")
result.to_a # Converts PG::Result to an array, 'result.as_json' converts to json
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does work. But maybe I didn't address my question well, I was wondering why `first_date` is gone with my query. I've gotten the answer from the other one. But still, thanks!

Comment: @CodaChang - I answered that question in first sentence of my answer. Please check above and you will understand. To add more to it, first_date is not recognized by Activity model.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the details. I understand now.